# Is my interpretation of "would not seem so" correct?

Tags: grammar

I did not feel insensible to his condescension, and would not seem so.[Source](http://www.loudlit.org/audio/jane_eyre/pages/14_12_jane_eyre.htm)

"wouldn't seem so"

Is this interpretation legitimate?
"I didn't wanna look like I was unaware of his condescension."

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, while to modern Western people, "condescension" is insulting", it didn't mean that back then.  We would be insulted by condescending behavior, a poor governess in Victorian England would be pleased by it.  She is saying that she was gratified by his attention, and therefore wished to be pleasing back.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the language used is a bit old-fashioned.  I think there's one further bit that you've missed:

> I did not feel insensible to his condescension

To "feel insensible" would mean here that the speaker has no emotional reaction or response to whatever actions are being taken; since the speaker does *not* feel insensible, this basically means "I was pleased by his attention to me",  with the additional sense as noted in @swbarnes' comment that the speaker is of a lower social status than the person giving her attention.

> and would not seem so

*Would* here is used in the sense of "desired" or "wished"; the speaker wishes to not appear as if she "feels insensible" to the attention being given.  That is, she doesn't want the person to think that she is ungrateful for his attention.

So, to rephrase it positively and in modern language:

> I wanted him to know that I appreciated his attentions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks right to me. The construction seems a little archaic, but that's what I'd expect from Jane Eyre.

Answer (score -1):

"Wouldn't" has 2 meanings. As Future in the Past and as a wish not to do something. 
Here it is the second one.

The first one would be grammatically incorrect. In this case it is not obvious WHAT wouldn't seem so. The problem is with the construction of the sentence. "would" should be in future to some action in the past. AND this action should be in the dependent clause.

> I hoped [that] it wouldn't seem so.

That is what you need in this sentence if you want to say that you didn't show your concern:

> I did not feel insensible to his condescension, and did not seem so

And in the text mentioned the heroine didn't **want** to show her concern. Also "wouldn't like to", "rather wouldn't" or simply "wouldn't".